# Qt Creator 2.70 is unable to load cuda shared library in Linux

Tags: qt, cuda, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I am running QT Creator 2.70 in Linux. The project compiles without any problem. But when I tried to launch the program that uses cuda libraries, the terminal launched by Qt Creator can't find the lib file. I can run the executable in the terminal launched by myself, where LD_LIBRARY_PATH has been properly setup.

Any one knows how to set up the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the terminal launched by QT Creator? I searched all the option in Qt Creator, but didn't find any option for doing that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in to `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

or you can set Qt project file *.pro, and set 
`LIBS += -L/path/ -lyourlib`